# Flask logging not working at all

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm trying to log messages in Flask both to file and to stdout. I've been reading the official Flask docs and came up with this:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    app.logger.debug('second test message...')
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Setup the logger
    file_handler = FileHandler('output.log')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
        '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
     ))
     handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
        '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
     ))
     app.logger.addHandler(handler)
     app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
     app.logger.error('first test message...')
     app.run()
```

There are several problems:

1. No `output.log` file is generated
2. Only the first logging message works:

   app.logger.error('testing...')

And only in stdout...the one in the view "/" does not even print to stdout... am I doing something wrong?

This is the output from starting the app and going to /:

```
2015-03-08 11:33:27,183 ERROR: first test message... [in /home/mosquito/python_projects/flask_tst/flask_tst.py:31]
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2015 11:33:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Does the process have write permissions to the log file?

Comment: Hello Klaus, yes, process has write permissions at project root folder

Comment: I got the same problem, even if the loglevel is set to info, all I got is error log. And in production mode, flask is run by uwsgi.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your (debug) logging messages are getting suppressed by Flask as you're not running in debug mode. If you set the following flag to True, your code will work.

```
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The messages will now appear as expected.

```
BennyE$ python3 stackoverflow.py 
2015-03-08 12:04:04,650 ERROR: firs test message... [in stackoverflow.py:31]
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
2015-03-08 12:04:04,807 ERROR: firs test message... [in stackoverflow.py:31]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in stackoverflow [stackoverflow.py:11]:
second test message...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-03-08 12:04:13,789 DEBUG: second test message... [in stackoverflow.py:11]
192.168.178.23 - - [08/Mar/2015 12:04:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in stackoverflow [stackoverflow.py:11]:
second test message...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-03-08 12:04:14,899 DEBUG: second test message... [in stackoverflow.py:11]
192.168.178.23 - - [08/Mar/2015 12:04:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This is the output in the associated output file:

```
BennyE$ cat output.log 
2015-03-08 11:58:22,226 ERROR: firs test message... [in stackoverflow.py:31]
2015-03-08 12:04:04,650 ERROR: firs test message... [in stackoverflow.py:31]
2015-03-08 12:04:04,807 ERROR: firs test message... [in stackoverflow.py:31]
2015-03-08 12:04:13,789 DEBUG: second test message... [in stackoverflow.py:11]
2015-03-08 12:04:14,899 DEBUG: second test message... [in stackoverflow.py:11]
```

Comment: From the Flask [Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/): "Flask will suppress any server error with a generic error page unless it is in debug mode. As such to enable just the interactive debugger without the code reloading, you have to invoke run() with debug=True and use_reloader=False. Setting use_debugger to True without being in debug mode won’t catch any exceptions because there won’t be any to catch."

Comment: Thanks for providing input on this. Really help resolve the issue(Though ignorance/blindspot) faster.

Comment: New link to the documentation about run (see Armin's comment) : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run

Comment: This answer is wrong. The correct answer is below, from kashaziz

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue and following worked for me:

```
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: make sure you're also importing the python standard lib logging module for this to work!

Answer (score 6):

Thansk BennyE_HH, it works.

But Flask didn't suppressed ERROR level log message even debug mode is disable(default is disable).

I think we should call `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to control log level even debug mode is false.

Answer (score 1):

Set it on the root logger as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852205/1701600)

```py
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case , I had need to set
`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`  in code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pathlib import Path
import json
import sys
import logging
import psycopg2
import re

# creating a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I configure logging settings for both the `console` and `file` outputs.
The file logs are automatically backed up at midnight.

```py
from flask import Flask
from logging.config import dictConfig
from pathlib import Path

app = Flask(__name__)

# logging
log_file_path = './log/backend.log'
Path(log_file_path).parent.mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok = True)

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {funcName} {lineno} {processName} {threadName} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'color_verbose': {
            'style': '%',
            '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
            'format': "%(yellow)s%(levelname)-5s%(cyan)s%(asctime)-24s%(red)s%(module)-10s%(green)s%(funcName)-12s%(white)s%(lineno)-5s%(purple)s%(processName)-12s%(white)s%(threadName)-12s%(blue)s%(message)s",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'color_verbose',
        },
        'flask': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': log_file_path,
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'encoding':'utf-8'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['flask','console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.logger.info('test info')
    app.logger.warning('test warning')
    app.logger.error('test error')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It gives output in the console like

```
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,653 scrape    <module>    335  MainProcess MainThread  test info
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:41,654 scrape    <module>    336  MainProcess MainThread  test warning
ERROR2024-03-11 19:48:41,654 scrape    <module>    337  MainProcess MainThread  test error
 * Serving Flask app 'scrape'
 * Debug mode: on
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread  Press CTRL+C to quit
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Restarting with stat
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:42,151 scrape    <module>    335  MainProcess MainThread  test info
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:42,151 scrape    <module>    336  MainProcess MainThread  test warning
ERROR2024-03-11 19:48:42,152 scrape    <module>    337  MainProcess MainThread  test error
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:42,154 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Debugger is active!
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:42,154 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Debugger PIN: 139-378-577
```

[image: output console]

requirement file :

```
Flask==3.0.2
colorama==0.4.6
colorlog==6.8.2
logging==0.4.9.6
```