# logging is not working under Flask in Python 3

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I was expecting the console to print the debug statement like "server starting on port...", but when I run `python app.py` for the following file, nothing prints out. I have already set my app to debug mode.

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from flask_env import MetaFlaskEnv
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer


class Configuration(metaclass=MetaFlaskEnv):
    """
    export PORT=80
    """
    DEBUG = True
    PORT = 5000

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOGGER.debug("server starting on port :" + str(app.config["PORT"]))
    HTTP_SERVER = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    HTTP_SERVER.listen(port=app.config["PORT"])
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting log level also on the root logger:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

or explicitly redirect the output to stdout using a handler:

```
import sys
import logging

root = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
root.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may either:

1. create handler for `LOGGER`
2. invoke `logging.basicConfig()`

**The first option is pretty straightforward**:

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler() 
LOGGER.addHandler(handler)
```

**The second needs some clarification**:

```
logging.basicConfig()
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Since you haven't provide handler, your logger will look for the handler in parent logger and so on... ...the case is - there is no default handler out-of-the-box. You have to provide some or set default with `basicConfig` call. Note, module-level convenience functions (`logging.info`, `logging.debug`, `logging.error`, ...) have got such a initialization and they call `basicConfig` internally if there is no handler.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I configure logging settings for both the `console` and `file` outputs.
The `file` logs are automatically backed up at midnight.

```py
from flask import Flask
from logging.config import dictConfig
from pathlib import Path

app = Flask(__name__)

# logging
log_file_path = './log/backend.log'
Path(log_file_path).parent.mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok = True)

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {funcName} {lineno} {processName} {threadName} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'color_verbose': {
            'style': '%',
            '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
            'format': "%(yellow)s%(levelname)-5s%(cyan)s%(asctime)-24s%(red)s%(module)-10s%(green)s%(funcName)-12s%(white)s%(lineno)-5s%(purple)s%(processName)-12s%(white)s%(threadName)-12s%(blue)s%(message)s",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'color_verbose',
        },
        'flask': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': log_file_path,
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'encoding':'utf-8'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['flask','console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.logger.info('test info')
    app.logger.warning('test warning')
    app.logger.error('test error')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It gives output in the console like

```
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,653 scrape    <module>    335  MainProcess MainThread  test info
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:41,654 scrape    <module>    336  MainProcess MainThread  test warning
ERROR2024-03-11 19:48:41,654 scrape    <module>    337  MainProcess MainThread  test error
 * Serving Flask app 'scrape'
 * Debug mode: on
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread  Press CTRL+C to quit
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:41,657 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Restarting with stat
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:42,151 scrape    <module>    335  MainProcess MainThread  test info
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:42,151 scrape    <module>    336  MainProcess MainThread  test warning
ERROR2024-03-11 19:48:42,152 scrape    <module>    337  MainProcess MainThread  test error
WARNING2024-03-11 19:48:42,154 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Debugger is active!
INFO 2024-03-11 19:48:42,154 _internal _log        96   MainProcess MainThread   * Debugger PIN: 139-378-577
```

[image: output console image]

requirement file :

```
Flask==3.0.2
colorama==0.4.6
colorlog==6.8.2
logging==0.4.9.6
```

Comment: Do not post [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141345/5211833) on multiple questions. If you think the *exact* same answer answers both questions, [flag them as a duplicate](/help/duplicates), thus associating this question with the target, keeping knowledge centralised. Otherwise, make sure to tailor the answer to each individual question.